# Using NLTK.wordnet in Anaconda Python: Error: Resource 'corpora/wordnet' not found

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet, anaconda

anyone has a suggestion about using nltk wordnet in Anaconda? I get this error after running: "from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn"

LookupError:

---

```
Resource 'corpora/wordnet' not found.  Please use the NLTK
Downloader to obtain the resource:  >>> nltk.download()
Searched in:
- 'C:\\Users\\hhuang/nltk_data'
- 'C:\\nltk_data'
- 'D:\\nltk_data'
- 'E:\\nltk_data'
- 'C:\\Users\\hhuang\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda\\nltk_data'
- 'C:\\Users\\hhuang\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda\\lib\\nltk_data'
- 'C:\\Users\\hhuang\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data'
```

Comment: As the error message suggests, you need to download the corpus: `import nltk; nltk.download()` to get started.

Comment: anaconda don't play nice with NLTK... Nevertheless, please follow these instructions to get the data: http://www.nltk.org/data.html